# Certificate issues when adding an IDP to an authentication service

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, sustainsys-saml2

I have an issue trying to add an idp to the authentication service.

My client is using forgerock login, and wants us to use SSO with SAML.

I have this working in an older project using Jitbit's simple SAML 2.0 component for ASP.NET
https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml/

But I am redesigning my application in .net core with identityserver4, and wanted to take advantage of the sustainsys implementation with the extra bells and whistles.

The type of SSO login is a simple redirect with ACS callback.

The information I have:
SamlEndpoint - The URL to redirect to
EntityId - My Entities Id
AcsUrl - the URL to return to
Certificate (string) (Taken from the metadata, which is not publicly available)

I have tried to do the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddSaml2(Saml2Defaults.Scheme,
                   options =>
                   {
                       options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("{MyEntityId}");
                       options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri($"ACS URL");
                       options.SPOptions.AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SigningBehavior.Never;
                       //options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new ServiceCertificate { 
                       //    Use = CertificateUse.Signing, 
                       //    Certificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes), 
                       //    Status = CertificateStatus.Current 
                       //});
                       var idp =
                           new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("IDP ID"), options.SPOptions)
                           {                                   
                               Binding = Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect,
                               LoadMetadata = false,
                               AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true, 
                               SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri("Redirect URL") 
                           };
                       options.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);
                   });
```

The exception I am getting is:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Missing signing certificate configuration on Idp

But I cannot see how to add my certificate? as it has no private/public key:

From the metadata

```
<ds:X509Data>                    
    <ds:X509Certificate>
        MIIDYTCCAk..........7tOxUus=                    
    </ds:X509Certificate>                
</ds:X509Data>
```

Looking for a steer in the right direction as I am failing to work it out.

If I try and add the certificate (commented out above) then I get no private key provided exception.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

This issue appears to be a "chicken and egg" issue where assigning the value for `LoadMetadata` is not a "safe" operation to perform while constructing a new instance of `IdentityProvider`.

The `set` property method for `IdentityProvider` also calls `Validate()` against your newly constructed `IdentityProvider` instance. In this case, you can see here the `Validate()` method being called:
https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/develop/Sustainsys.Saml2/IdentityProvider.cs#L123. Not to worry too much since the private backing field, `loadMetadata`, is already `false` (default value).

The problem here is that you're not yet given the ability to add your IdP signing certificate (`idp.SigningKeys.Add(...)`) before `Validate()` is called.

You need to:

1. Create your `idp`, do not yet set `LoadMetadata`
2. Add your signing keys or make any other configuration settings you need
3. If desired, you can explicitly set `LoadMetadata` (optional in your case since it's already `false`)

That should resolve this error and get you on your way.

BTW, your signing certificate needs to have a private key. I would suggest generating something like a PFX (PKCS#12, PKCS#8, etc.) and you can import that file directly into an `X509Certificate2` with the password set, be sure to set the options with `MachineKeySet | Exportable` so your private key is accessible: e.g.

```cs
byte[] pfx = null; // TODO: Get your actual certificate, read from file, DB, memory, etc.
var signingCert = new X509Certificate2(
    pfx,
    "password",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```